# Create Dataframe from tuple list with dynamic schema in pyspark

Tags: pyspark

I am trying to create a dataframe  with dynamic schema from tuple list in pyspark

here is my code for tuple list

```
outputlist= []
for row in df2.collect():
   tmpList = row 
   temptuple = ()
   id = tmpList[0]
   temptuple = temptuple+(id,)
   print(id)
   for val in range (1,len(tmpList)):
     if tmpList[val] is None:
     break
     else :
      value = tmpList[val]
      index = val
      if index > 1:
        index =1
        temptuple = temptuple+ (value,)
        temptuple = temptuple+ (index,)

outputlist.append(temptuple)
print(outputlist)
```

[('44038:4132', '324772', 1), ('44038:4291', '772122995105', 1, '477212299170', 1)]

Until here it is okay, now i have to create a dataframe with dynamic schema using above values

for example when dataframe read first tuple it should give result like this
if you see in screenshot value 324772 is coming as field name

and when dataframe read second tuple , it should give results like this
if you see in screenshot value 772122995105,477212299170 is coming as field name and so on

[image: screenshot]

Comment: And what is the column name for the first value `44038:4132`? Your question is not clear.

Comment: id is the column name for 44038:4132

Comment: apologies, i have defined screenshot correctly now

Answer (score 0):

See the following code:

```
tuples = [('44038:4132', '324772', 1), ('44038:4291', '772122995105', 1, '477212299170', 1)]

for tuple in tuples:
    id = tuple[0]
    tmp_tuple = tuple[1:]

    cols = {}

    for i in range(int(len(tmp_tuple) / 2)):
        j = i * 2
        cols[tmp_tuple[j]] = tmp_tuple[j + 1]

    tmp_dict = {
        "id": id,
        **cols
    }

    cols_keys = cols.keys()
    df = spark.createDataFrame(Row(tmp_dict))
    df = df.select("id", *cols_keys)
    df.show()
```

Here is the sample output:

```
+----------+------+
|        id|324772|
+----------+------+
|44038:4132|     1|
+----------+------+

+----------+------------+------------+
|        id|772122995105|477212299170|
+----------+------------+------------+
|44038:4291|           1|           1|
+----------+------------+------------+
```